# How to read the Git lab console output to fail the job when the test fails

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci.yml

I want to read the gitlab console output to fail the job when the test fails. I am running SoapUI tests using maven. Please see the screenshot below. I am new to gitlab. I have been working on this issue for 2 weeks. Also it is becoming hard for me to click on each job to see if it has passed or failed.
If I can read the console output, I can put an if condition in the yml file stating that it should fail the job if it see the text "failed"

[image: Console output screenshot]

Here is the .yml file

```
# Wa API
.wa-stage:
  stage: wa
  needs: []

TC-396:
  extends: .wa-stage
  image: adoptopenjdk/maven-openjdk11
  variables:
   MAVEN_CLI_OPTS: "-Dmaven.test.failure.ignore=false"
  script:
  - 'mvn -f ./S/Wa/TC-396-soapui/pom.xml $MAVEN_CLI_OPTS test'
  allow_failure: true
  when: always

TC-397:
  extends: .wa-stage
  image: adoptopenjdk/maven-openjdk11
  variables:
   MAVEN_CLI_OPTS: "-Dmaven.test.failure.ignore=false"
  script:
  - 'mvn -f ./S/Wa/TC-397-soapui/pom.xml $MAVEN_CLI_OPTS test'
  allow_failure: true

  when: always

TC-398:
  extends: .wa-stage
  image: adoptopenjdk/maven-openjdk11
  variables:
   MAVEN_CLI_OPTS: "-Dmaven.test.failure.ignore=false"
  script:
  - 'mvn -f ./S/Wa/TC-398-soapui/pom.xml $MAVEN_CLI_OPTS test'
  allow_failure: true

  when: always

TC-399:
  extends: .wa-stage
  image: adoptopenjdk/maven-openjdk11
  variables:
   MAVEN_CLI_OPTS: "-Dmaven.test.failure.ignore=false"
  script:
  - 'mvn -f ./S/Wa/TC-399-soapui/pom.xml $MAVEN_CLI_OPTS test'
  allow_failure: true

  when: always
```

Screenshot if all the tests go well
[image]

Comment: This should happen without you having to do anything. But we’ll need to see your test setup to help. Can you show us your .gitab-ci.yml file and an example of a job which fails and then GitLab reports as a success? It’s hard to debug with only a case which succeeded and then (correctly) reported a success.

Comment: Thanks Michael for your response. Please see the yml attached.

Comment: If you delete `allow_failure: true` does that resolve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

This do minimal work with python:

test01.py:

```
print(f'fail')
```

.gitlab-ci.yml

```
image: python:3.11-alpine

stages:
  - build

PythonBuild:
  stage: build
#  script:
#    - python test01.py
  script:
    - OUT=$(python test01.py)
    - echo "$OUT"
    - if [ "$OUT" = "fail" ]; then echo "Tests failed" ; exit 1; fi


# success
#exit 0
```

gitlab output
[image]